# eclipse is not opening as jvm greater version requried in linux machine

Tags: jvm

I'm new to linux machines. I have installed java 1.8 on linux machine and by default I got java 1.6 installed on this. I have set path in ~/.bashrc 
PATH= /JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

When I try to open eclipse throws an error "version 1.6.0_17 of jvm is not suitable for this product. 1.7 or greater version is requried". 
I have eclipse MARS and java 1.8 is requried according to my business requirement.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: After you added to your `.bashrc` did you make sure it had changed the path of your terminal. i.e. did you reload it? BTW There is no difference to adding an environment variable is Windows when you have an open  CMD prompt.

Comment: is that correct - `PATH=/JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` ? Should probably be `PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}`

Comment: yes, I reloaded. Even after that same issue. @PeterLawrey

Comment: PATH is working fine. i tried #java -version showing correct output. Issue is some other @sisyphus